# Try-except script hangs instead of giving an error

Tags: python, try-except

I'm having trouble in writing a script for reading some temperature sensors (DS18B20) on a raspberry pi.
I have a working script, but sometimes the sensors fall out and then the script also stops.
I'm trying to make a more robust version by integrating a try-except statement. The goal is to proceed to the next sensor in the range if one of the sensors doesn't react. If I emulate sensor failure by plugging one of the sensors out, the script stops taking measurements for all the sensors (instead of for the sensor that has been plugged out). And it doesn't give me an error. Any ideas?

This is the part of the script with the try statement:

```
if time.time() <= timeout:
    for index in range (numsensors):
        try: 

                def read_temp_raw(): # gets the temps one by one
                        f = open(device_file[index], 'r')
                        lines = f.readlines()
                        f.close()
                        return lines
                def read_temp(): # checks the received temperature for errors
                     lines = read_temp_raw()
                     while lines[0].strip()[-3:] != 'YES':
                        time.sleep(0.2)
                        lines = read_temp_raw()
                     equals_pos = lines[1].find('t=')
                     if equals_pos != -1:
                        temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:]
                        # set proper decimal place for deg C
                        temp = float(temp_string) / 1000.0
                        # Round temp to x decimal points --> round(temp,x)
                        temp = round(temp, 2)
                        return temp


                reading = (read_temp())
                temp[index].append(reading)
                print device[index],"=", temp[index]
                continue
        except IOError:
            print "Error"
```

Comment: Well, you have some potentially infinite loop there. Did you try to check whether the loops keep running forever or not?

Comment: Also the `continue` at the end is redundant.

Comment: I'd guess the problem is the `while` loop in `read_temp`. The file you're reading with `read_temp_raw()` is probably empty, so the condition becomes `while "" != 'YES'`, which loops infinitely (or until you re-connect the sensor).

Answer (score 0):

## "What has been asked" inventory:

1. **Is** using `try-except` construct making underlying system more
   robust?
2. **Why** is the code not giving any error on indicated sensor-failure?

---

**A1:**
The **`try-except`** clause sounds as self-explanatory & life-saving package, however it is not.

One has to fully understand **what** all sorts of **`exceptions`**-types the code is expecting to meet face-to-face **and** how to handle each of them. Naive or erroneous use of this syntax construct effectively masks the rest of the exceptions from your debugging radar screen, leaving the unhandled cases fail in a dark silence, out of your control and without knowing about them at all. True "*Robustness*" and "*Failure Resilience*" is something else than this.

This code sample will leave hidden all real-life collisions, except the only one listed, the `IOError`, but if that will not happen, all the others, that do happen, are not handled:

```
if time.time() <= timeout:              # START if .time() is still before a T/O
    for index in range (numsensors):    #       ITERATE over all sensors
        try:                            #           TRY:
            <<<something>>>             #                 <<<something>>>
        except IOError:                 #           EXC IOError:
            <<<IOError__>>>             #                 Handle EXC.IOError
```

Guess all your `def...(..):`-s may belong to a non-repeating section of the code, prior to the `if:/for:` as you need not modify the code "on-the-fly", do you?

```
def read_temp_raw():                    # DEF: gets the temps one by one
    f = open(device_file[index],'r')    #      SET aFileHANDLE access to IO.DEV ( beware var index "visibility" )
    lines = f.readlines()               #      IO.DEV.READ till <EoF>
    f.close()                           #      IO.DEV.CLOSE
    return lines                        #      RET all lines

def read_temp():                        # DEF: checks the received temperature for errors
    lines = read_temp_raw()             #      GET lines from read_temp_raw()
    while lines[0].strip()[-3:]!='YES': #      WHILE last-3Bytes of 1st-line!="YES"
        time.sleep(0.2)                 #          NOP/Sleep()
        lines = read_temp_raw()         #          GET lines again (beware var index)
        equals_pos =lines[1].find('t=') #          SET position of 't=' in 2nd-line
        if equals_pos != -1:            #          IF  position != -1
            temp_string = lines[1][equals_pos+2:]                
            temp = float(temp_string) \
            / 1000.0                    #              DIV( 1000) decimal place for deg C
            temp = round(temp, 2)       #              ROUND temp to x decimal points --> round(temp,x)
            return temp                 #              RET->

        # ----------------------------- #          ELSE: re-loop in WHILE
     # -------------------------------- #     LOOP AGAIN AD INFIMUM
```

**A2:** your `try-except` clause in the posted code is expecting only one kind of exception to be handled by it -- the **`IOError`** -- which is instantiated only when actual IO.DEV operation *fails for an I/O-related reason*, which does not mean a case, that you physically "un-plug" a sensor, while the IO.DEV is still present and can carry it's IO.DEV.READ(s) and thus no `exceptions.EnvironmentError.IOError` is to be `raise`-d

That means, the IO.DEV.READ(s) take place and the code results, as per the condition `WHILE last-3Bytes of 1st-line` dictates, in an endless loop, because the 1st-line "still" does not end with "YES".
Q.E.D.

---

### The Goal focus

Coming back to the issue, you may rather set a safer test for a real-world case, where an erroneous input may appear during your sensor-network scan.

The principle may look like:

```
f.close()                           #      IO.DEV.CLOSE
if ( len(lines) < 2 ):              #      IF <<lines>> are nonsense:
    return [ "NULL_LENGTH_READING still with CODE EXPECTED ACK-SIG-> YES",        \
             "SIG ERROR FOR POST-PROCESSOR WITH AN UNREALISTIC VALUE t=-99999999" \
             ]
return( lines )                     #      OTHERWISE RET( lines )
```